# ios swift programming with view..visible and view.gone

Tags: swift

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt8RK.png)

how to implement like this logic  in ios with buttons and if user tapped photos present photos in nested view and if user tapped videos present videos nested view and work with view Visibility and visibility.Gone

Comment: If you at least put some effort into your question, you won't get all the downvotes and will receive a helpful answer.

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent of `visibility.INVISIBLE` and `visibility.VISIBLE` would probably be

```
view.isHidden = true
view.isHidden = false
```

So if a understand correctly you want to hide your videos view and show the photos view and vice versa so:

```
 videosView.isHidden = true
 photosView.isHidden = false
```

to show photos and hide videos and the other way around to show videos and hide photos.

Although to create a similar layout as your screenshot you may want to just use a `tabBarViewController` instead of hiding / showing views.